# ¿Cómo generar el sello de un CFDI?

Tags: c#, sha1

Estoy creando un modulo para poder generar los archivos XML de un CFDI. Uno de los puntos es generar un sello digital, he seguido los pasos de diferentes guías que describen en diferentes lenguajes el proceso que debe tener con los algoritmos `SHA-1` y `RSA`.

En mi código, incluso tengo implementados dos procesos, uno con la librería `opensslkey` y otro con librerías nativas de C#, los dos me devuelven el mismo resultado. El problema está en que los validadores me dicen que el sello esta mal formado o es inválido.

¿Tienen idea del por qué puede ser? (enseguida mi código).

```
private string generaSello()
{
    string strSello = string.Empty;
    string strPathLlave = CFDI.Properties.Settings.Default.llave;
    string strLlavePwd = CFDI.Properties.Settings.Default.clave;
    string strCadenaOriginal = generaCadena(); // Aquí ya haber generado la cadena original

    System.Security.SecureString passwordSeguro = new System.Security.SecureString();
    passwordSeguro.Clear();

    foreach (char c in strLlavePwd.ToCharArray())
        passwordSeguro.AppendChar(c);

    byte[] llavePrivadaBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(strPathLlave);
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = opensslkey.DecodeEncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(llavePrivadaBytes, passwordSeguro);

    SHA1Managed sha = new SHA1Managed();
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(generaCadena());
    byte[] digest = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);

    RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter RSAFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa);
    RSAFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
    byte[] SignedHashValue = RSAFormatter.CreateSignature(digest);

    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] bytesFirmados = rsa.SignData(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strCadenaOriginal), hasher);
    strSello = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesFirmados);  // Y aquí está el sello
    string r = Convert.ToBase64String(SignedHashValue);// Y aquí está el sello 2 

    return strSello;
    //return r;
}
```

Este es un ejemplo del XML formado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd" version="3.2" folio="0" fecha="2017-04-18T18:19:17" sello="iMTGK5FHmLpudWYIxLP99/h44JMErjg1bNLtblp/YvVAVTPMiMlwEF9Y+44wHOVeQ2u36xnl1aVVCL9T8fyUQwFRCmd9PtFWdAmSQrpHK914gomk31W+Hunrdrwj0Asewyn/wl1fVaJbeV2R0cVsdvrWJXhx3YguJPmyvrE+u7U=" formaDePago="0" noCertificado="20001000000200001428" certificado="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" subTotal="1" TipoCambio="1.00" Moneda="Peso Mexicano" total="1" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" metodoDePago="02,99" LugarExpedicion="Av. Cerro Gordo del Campestre 201 301, Las Quintas, 37125, León, León de los Aldama, Guanajuato, México" NumCtaPago="NO IDENTIFICADO">
    <cfdi:Emisor rfc="DRD091113A70" nombre="DESARROLLOS RESIDENCIALES DE LEON SA DE CV">
        <cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="Av. Cerro Gordo del Campestre" noExterior="201" noInterior="301" colonia="Las quintas" localidad="León de los Aldama" municipio="León" estado="Guanajuato" pais="México" codigoPostal="37125" />
        <cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="PERSONA MORAL REGIMEN GENERAL" />
    </cfdi:Emisor>
    <cfdi:Receptor rfc="AAHA6301152K1" nombre="ABRAHAM ARAIZA HERNANDEZ">
        <cfdi:Domicilio calle="VIA AUREA" noExterior="440" colonia="VILLA MAGNA" municipio="SAN LUIS POTOSÍ" estado="SAN LUIS POTOSÍ" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="78413" />
    </cfdi:Receptor>
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1" unidad="NO APLICA" descripcion="VENTA DE TERRENO&amp;#xA;LOTE 36 MZ 64 DE LA PRIVADA MAYORAZGO LA GAVIA DE CONFORMIDAD CON EL FIDEICOMISO DE BANCO DEL BAJIO NO. 10153-10-34 DE FECHA 24 DE ENERO DE 2011" valorUnitario="1" importe="1" />
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos />
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Comment: Si eres de México; igual quise abordar el tema para hacerlo en automático; los elementos que creas si no están registrados ante el SAT no serán validos para ellos; hay PAC que pueden generarlos; pero realmente es el SAT quien los crea y guarda; por consiguiente son válidos. No es que coincida la cadena, es un proceso que el SAT realiza y devuelve para ser incluido.

Comment: ¿Te has documentado al respecto?, supongo que hablas de los XML del SAT, entra a la pagina del SAT allí debe estar TODA la información.  El Sello se genera a partir de la cadena original, ¿correcto?, si generas un sello diferente al que genera el validador, es porque .... No se esta armando bien la cadena, o no usas la encriptación correcta.  Recomiendo este programa: [Valida CFD](http://www.ploteo.com.mx/validacfdfiles/demos/ValidaCFDSetup.zip), o puedes vaildar online allí podrás comparar la cadena de ellos con la tuya [validarXML](http://www.validaxml.com/) y asi arreglar tus detalles.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas  Tu hablas del TIMBRADO, ese si lo debe hacer un PAC oficial, el SELLO se genera en base a la CADENA ORIGINAL, ese lo puedes hacer sin ningun problema... El TIMBRADO lo debe hacer un PAC o el propio SAT, en este paso se valida el XML y agrega la sección de timbrado donde viene el codigo UUID del SAT

Comment: El plan es usar un PAC, como dice @Cristina, la CADENA ORIGINAL la formo con el xslt del sat, y sobre los archivos de certificado, estoy usando los de prueba que proporciona también el sat. sobre los validadores, con ellos me doy en el punto de que el sello esta mal formado

Comment: @GermanAT sube uno de tus XML que generas, tendrias que comprar eso contra los Errores arrojados en la validación, allí te dice exactamente que cosa esta "incorrecta", al armar los XML es importante los atributos y los tags XML deben ser tal cual lo pone el sat, respetando mayusculas y minusculas, tambien hay ciertos campos como el tipo de moneda, forma de pago, que deben venir de un catalogo del SAT, muchas facturas tienen error por eso, ponen MONEDA NACIONAL, en lugar de 03, que es el código del catalogo del SAT, tienes que revisar muy bien la doc. oficial del SAT.

Comment: Actualice el tema con un ejemplo de XML, en los validadores el mensaje solo dice "Sello mal formado o invalido"

Comment: @GermanAT ok, lo que te digo es que compares la cadena que genera el validador con la que tu generas...  en el software que te mencione en el comentario inicial se muestra la cadena... en esta pagina tambien peudes probar sellando uno de tus XMLS: [Pagina sello](http://solucionfactible.com/sfic/capitulos/timbrado/sello.jsp)

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo Ya corrí el programa que compartiste, me dice lo mismo: "Sello del Emisor Invalido". sobre la pagina, de hecho es una de las que consulte para ir generando el código, tristemente mi resultado del sello no es igual.

Comment: COMPARA LA CADENA QUE GENERÓ EL VALIDADOR CONTRA LA QUE TU MANDAS PARA HACER EL SELLO, allí esta tu detalle, es como la 3 vez que te sugiero esto, si se genera diferente es porque algo tienes diferente en el origen de datos, ¿Me estoy explicando?

Comment: Si ya estas seguro que TODO se esta ARMANDO "Conforme a lo que dice el SAT"... entonces deberías enviarle correo algún PAC para que te asesore, y de preferencia al que vayas a contratar para el timbrado, así están obligados a darte el soporte.

Comment: yo tuve el mismo problema al crear mi sistema, la verdad encontré una solución que consiste en una DLL llamada EasyONE, y realmente me fue muy bien.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mira te recomiendo que compares tu cadena(la que envías para generar el sello) con la que esta generando el validador:

NOTA: Tu utilizas versión 3.2... al parecer ya estamos en 3.3, no se si por allí vaya tu detalle.  Y eso se resume en error de estructura, lo cual llevaría a error en la formación de la cadena original y por ende error en el sello.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cadena**

||3.2|2017-04-18T18:19:17|ingreso|0|1|1.00|Peso Mexicano|1|02,99|Av. Cerro Gordo del Campestre 201 301, Las Quintas,
37125, León, León de los Aldama, Guanajuato, México|NO IDENTIFICADO|DRD091113A70|DESARROLLOS
RESIDENCIALES DE LEON SA DE CV|Av. Cerro Gordo del Campestre|201|301|Las quintas|León de los
Aldama|León|Guanajuato|México|37125|PERSONA MORAL REGIMEN GENERAL|AAHA6301152K1|ABRAHAM ARAIZA
HERNANDEZ|VIA AUREA|440|VILLA MAGNA|SAN LUIS POTOSÍ|SAN LUIS POTOSÍ|MEXICO|78413|1|NO APLICA|VENTA
DE TERRENO
LOTE 36 MZ 64 DE LA PRIVADA MAYORAZGO LA GAVIA DE CONFORMIDAD CON EL
FIDEICOMISO DE BANCO DEL BAJIO NO. 10153-10-34 DE FECHA 24 DE ENERO DE 2011|1|1||

**Sello**

iMTGK5FHmLpudWYIxLP99/h44JMErjg1bNLtblp/YvVAVTPMiMlwEF9Y+44wHOVeQ2u36xnl1aVVCL9T8fyUQwFRCmd9PtF
WdAmSQrpHK914gomk31W+Hunrdrwj0Asewyn/wl1fVaJbeV2R0cVsdvrWJXhx3YguJPmyvrE+u7U=

**Validaciones**

Uno de los errores dice que el folio es incorrecto:

*cfdi:Comprobante: El valor del atributo "FOLIO" no es válido, no cumple con la estructura definida por el SAT, debe ser mayor a cero.*

Otro de los erores dice:

*El certificado no pertenece al emisor del documento.*

Creo que esta validación es importante..

Comment: al parecer el código esta bien, pero esta respuesta me hizo voltear a ver mi cadena original y de ahí mis datos de llanado, se va un carácter especial que estava causando todo el alboroto

Comment: Qué bien que ya lo resolviste.  A veces es muy tedioso estar armando las cadenas, y probar, llega el punto en el que se puede ir un detallito y creamos que todo esta correcto, nos saturamos pues...